# How to combine these 2 methods in order to print a dynamic game board?

Tags: java

My school requires us to make a TicTacToe game with dynamic game board. I have done nothing like this before because it wasn't required and I am not good at programming. I've tried to look for example codes and videos but nothing has been helpful for me.

I've successfully made method that asks the sizes (width and height) from the user and another one that prints game board, which is just *'s for borders and -'s for empty places. I don't really care how my game looks as long as it works but if there is any technical reason why the board should be different, please let me know.

PROBLEM: I don't know how to combine these two files to make it work so it asks 2 values from user and print NxM game board.

This one asks width and height separately from the user:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Size {

    static void askSize() {

        System.out.println("Hello!");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Insert width of the game board (3-9)");
        int width = scan.nextInt();
        while (width < 3 || width > 9) {
            System.out.println("Insert width again (has to be between 3 and 9)");
            width = scan.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println("Insert height of the game board (3-9)");
        int height = scan.nextInt();
        while (height < 3 || height > 9) {
            System.out.println("Insert height again (has to be between 3 and 9)");
            height = scan.nextInt();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        askSize();
    }
}
```

This one prints board using values determined on main-method:

```
class Board {
    static void printGameBoard(int n, int m) {
    
        int i, j;
        for (i=-1; i<=n; i++){
            for (j=-1; j<=m; j++){
                if (i==-1 || i==n || j==-1 || j==m)
                    System.out.print("*");
                else 
                    System.out.print("-");
                }
                System.out.println(); 
            }
        }

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        int rows = 3, columns = 3;
        printGameBoard(rows, columns);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are required to attend this course, I suggest try learning again until you understand the basics. You have a code to read Height and Width (which is basically Row and Column), and another code that requires row and column to work. Are you really sure that you [have done the best you can?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Right now you have two different classes that don't interact with each other. You also have to `main` methods. One program should have *one* main method.
What you need to do is to figure out how the interaction between your classes should look like.

For this example, this is pretty straight forward. Both classes only have one method, which is also *static*. This means, you have one `main` method, simply ask for the size, and pass that size to `Board` to print the game board.

But to do this, it is required that your `askSize()` does actually return a value so you can work with it further. For this instance, it should actually return two integers, height and width. So you could return an integer array, containing the height and with. But the better approach is to restructure your `Size` class like this:

```
class Size {
    
    private static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    static int askForWidth() {
        System.out.println("Hello!");
        System.out.println("Insert width of the game board (3-9)");
        int width = scan.nextInt();
        while (width < 3 || width > 9) {
            System.out.println("Insert width again (has to be between 3 and 9)");
            width = scan.nextInt();
        }
        return width;
    }
    
    static int askForHeight() {
        System.out.println("Insert height of the game board (3-9)");
        int height = scan.nextInt();
        while (height < 3 || height > 9) {
            System.out.println("Insert height again (has to be between 3 and 9)");
            height = scan.nextInt();
        }
        return height;
    }
}
```

That way, you can retrieve the width and height in a straightforward way.
What would also make sense, is to make the method(s) in `Size` not static, and then save the size parameters as class variables, which you then can retrieve once you created a `Size` instance.

After that, the main method should simply be structured like this in your case:

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
    int columns = askForWidth();
    int rows = askForHeight();
    printGameBoard(rows, columns);
}
```